# How to test a directive containing a text field in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive containing a text field, and I want to test to make sure that the text entered into the field makes it to the model.

The directive:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var module = require('reporting/js/directives/app.directives');
  var template = require('text!reporting/templates/text.box.tpl');

  module.directive('textField', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      template:template,
      scope: {
        textField : "=",
        textBoxResponses : "="
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.debug = function () {
          scope;
          // debugger;
        };
      }
    };
  });

  return module;
});
```

The markup:

```
<div ng-form name="textBox">
  <!-- <button ng-click="debug()">debug the text box button</button> -->
  <h1>Text Box!</h1>
  {{textField.label}} <input type="text" name="textBox" ng-model="textBoxResponses[textField.fieldName]">{{name}}
</div>
```

The test code:

```
/* global inject, expect, angular */

define(function(require){
  'use strict';
  require('angular');
  require('angularMock');
  require('reporting/js/directives/app.directives');
  require('reporting/js/directives/text.box.directive');

  describe("builder experimenter", function() {
    var directive, scope;
    beforeEach(module('app.directives'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope;

      scope.textBoxResponses = {};
      scope.textBoxField = {
        fieldName : "textBox1"
      };
      directive = angular.element('<div text-field="textBoxField" text-box-responses="textBoxResponses"></div>');
      $compile(directive)(scope);
      scope.$digest();


    }));
    it('should put the text box value on the model', inject(function() {
      directive.find(":text").val("something");
      expect(scope.textBoxResponses.textBox1).toBe("something");
    }));
  });
});
```

So, what I'm trying to do in the last it block is to simulate typing in the text field, and then check to make sure that the new value of the text field makes it to the model. The issue is that the model is never updated with the new value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `ng-model` is never informed that anything is in the textfield.  `ng-model` is listening for the `input` event.  All you have to do to fix your code is:

```
  var text = directive.find(":text");
  text.val("something");
  text.trigger('input');
  expect(scope.textBoxResponses.textBox1).toBe("something");
```

When the `ng-model` gets the event `input`, then check your scope and everything will be what you expect.

Comment: good answer. just to add - the reason one does not need an explicit `scope.$digest()` before `expect()` is because input directive's event handler wraps call to `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(txt)` in `scope.$apply()` as needed

Answer (score 0):

I got this done by using the sniffer service.

Your test will look like this:

```
var sniffer;
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $sniffer) {
  scope = $rootScope;
  sniffer = $sniffer;
  scope.textBoxResponses = {};
  scope.textBoxField = {
    fieldName : "textBox1"
  };
  directive = angular.element('<div text-field="textBoxField" text-box-responses="textBoxResponses"></div>');
  $compile(directive)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
}));
it('should put the text box value on the model', inject(function() {
  directive.find(":text").val("something");
  directive.find(":text").trigger(sniffer.hasEvent('input') ? 'input' : 'change');
  expect(directive.isolateScope().textBoxResponses.textBox1).toBe("something");
}));
```

I found this pattern here: [angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead test](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/test/typeahead.spec.js)

The trigger basically makes the view value go into the model.

Hope this helps